# Why isn't my partial view getting rendered when I click my button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The goal is to load the partial view without refreshing the entire page, just the partial view iteself, and when I do that, I want the model that I'm passing into the view *the int* to increment.

But when I try to load the view by pressing my button it says..

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location in Console
```

It's interesting because in the console it also outputs

```
<h1>Hello from _Items partial view. + 1</h1>
```

This is my index.cshtml

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="LoadInfo()">Load</button>
<div class="text-center">

</div>


<script>
    function LoadInfo() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/LoadView",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Did it get called is the question..");
                console.log("Response: " + response);
                $(".text-center").load(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And the partial view

```
@model int

<h1>Hello from _Items partial view. + @Model</h1>
```

As well as the controller

```
int i = 0;
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult LoadView()
{
    i++;
    return PartialView("_Items", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "Home/LoadView",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Did it get called is the question..");
                console.log("Response: " + response);
                $(".text-center").html(response);
            }
        });
```

The load() method loads data from a server i.e. if you want to load data from any file then you can use load(). But as you are getting data from partial view and partial view returns HTML document which you need to add into selected div. so, whenever you'll use partial view then try to avoid using load().

Comment: Could you explain the difference between .load() and .html()?

Comment: The load() method loads data from a server i.e. if you want to load data from any file then you can use load(). But as you are getting data from partial view and partial view returns HTML document which you need to add into selected div. so, whenever you'll use partial view then try to avoid using load().

Comment: Oh sorry, I wanted you to put it in your answer so it's clear to anyone else having the same issue and not understanding the reason your code works and the OG code doesn't.

Comment: I did the edit on your behalf. Should show up if it's approved.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rutuja said, you need to change `.load() to .html()` method to solve your current issue.

> Another thing, I found that you used the variable `i` to display the
> number of clicks.
>
> If you want to increase the number of `i` based on the number of times
> you click `Load`, then your current approach is impossible to achieve,
> it will always only display `1`.

Because every time you click the `Load` button, you are re-entering the `LoadView` method of the entire controller, so `i` will be re-assigned the default value of 0, instead of superimposing based on the previous data.

To achieve the number of clicks, **I suggest that you pass the i variable value from js to LoadView**, as shown below:

```
<script>
        var i = 0;
        function LoadInfo() {
            i++;
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/LoadView?i=" + i,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("Did it get called is the question..");
                    console.log("Response: " + response);
                    $(".text-center").html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
       [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult LoadView(int i)
        {
            return PartialView("_Items", i);
        }
```

Here is the result:

[image]